# XSLT navigating through tag levels

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to write an xml transform using XSLT 1.0, completely new to this so picking it up on the fly, my question is this:
if I have a for each loop such that

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content" >
<xsl:if test="string(@version) = 'Series'">
```

The if statement is there to check a string that's embedded in the tag, it looks like:

```
<Content version="Series" action="update">
```

Now my question is that I need another for each loop inside the current for each loop but it needs to look at the same level ( ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content) and if I created another for each loop with that as the select it would be looking in

```
 ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content/ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content
```

which isn't helpful. I need to look at the same level and use a different if statment to read that version string. This is because I need an output that will use children to build a tree. Unfortunately I can't change the input xml it ranks series, title and version all on the same level and I need to force them into being structured

Cheers

Comment: I would really advise you to do some reading. There are some tricky concepts in XSLT: one of them is the notion of "context" which you are asking about here. You won't find out how it works by trial and error, you need to read about it.

Comment: Cheers for the advice, have you got any good resources? I've been looking through the w3schools information for it which has helped me quite a bit so far. This is completely alien to the sort of programming I'm used to

Comment: w3schools, in my view, is useful for looking up things you once new but have forgotten, but it's hopeless for teaching new concepts. I would never start writing in a new language without first buying a book. There are books at every level on XSLT; mine is designed for people who like probing every obscure corner, others like Jeni Tennison's are better for people who want a gentle introduction.

Comment: Don't suppose you'd have a link to where I could buy either of those? It looks like I'm going to be doing XSLT for a while!

Comment: Try http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=XSLT+Kay+Tennison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say *Unfortunately I can't change the input xml*, but this is XSLT...of course you can change it, right before you process it. But you don't need to.

XSL has the concept of "context node" within your current template, so you should be able to select on

```
select="../ns0:Content/..."
```

However you can select them directly, too (in your original select):

```
select="ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content[@version='Series']"
```

or relatively:

```
select="../ns0:Content[@version='Series']"
```

And just provide different templates for each, if that's what you need.

To me it sounds like you want to select the parent of these elements `ns0:BxfData` and use relative-to-context selectors to write out a tree instead of a list. Then you may not need `for-each` at all.

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData">
  <xsl:element name="Rank">
    <xsl:element name="Series>
      <xsl:copy-of select="./ns0:Content[@version='Series']/@action" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Title">
      <xsl:copy-of select="./ns0:Content[@version='Title']/@action" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Version">
      <xsl:copy-of select="./ns0:Content[@version='Version']/@action" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Should emit new XML that looks like this:

```
<Rank>
  <Series action="update" />
  <Title action="..." />
  <Version action="..." />
</Rank>
```

I may have syntax slightly off (it's been awhile since I've done any transforms), but the idea should be clear. This template, combined with a generic template to copy all the nodes you'd like to keep by default should work without any need for loops.

Comment: This was perfect thank you very much :) solved my problem in no time at all